Add key => value pair to existing index of PHP array
I have this PHP array:-
$tblData[] = array(
    "Orange" => "Healthy",
    "Apple" => "Good",
    "Pizza" => "Bad",
);

This is the output:-
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Orange] => Healthy
            [Apple] => Good
            [Pizza] => Bad
        )

)

Now, if I add this:-
$tblData[] = array(
    "Hot dogs" => "Big No",
);

This is the output:-
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Orange] => Healthy
            [Apple] => Good
            [Pizza] => Bad
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Hot dogs] => Big No
        )

)

I want the new key value pair, i.e., "Hot dogs" => "Big No" to be added under "Pizza" => "Bad" i.e., under the index [0] as an item, like this:-
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Orange] => Healthy
            [Apple] => Good
            [Pizza] => Bad
            [Hot dogs] => Big No
        )

)

I have tried specifying the index, tried array_push and array_merge. But, I can't get it right.

$tblData[0][] = array(

$tblData[0] += array("Hot dogs" => "Big No");

For future reference you should always show the code you tried. "Can't get it right" isn't an error message or useful problem statement. In this case the solution is trivial but it might not be, if you ask something more complicated. See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] if the issue

@ADyson I have added all the information to show the error just above the "Can't get it right" with the exact code and it's output. Please help me understand what's missing here. Is it the command I am using to print the array?

Thumb rule is that empty brackets [] are only used to append values at the end of an array. To update an existing value you always need to supply the keys to identify the element (or invoke some function that does advanced array manipulations).

@NoobYT There is only one answer to accept, you cannot accept Comments :) but the Answer is not correct

@NoobYT you said tried array_push and array_merge. But, I can't get it right. There are no examples of what you tried with those functions. Again it doesn't  really matter so much in this case because the solution is obvious anyway, but I'm just pointing out that the devil is often in the detail in more complex cases. Something to look at next time you ask a question, that's all.

@Wiimm no, it would need to be $tblData[0]["Hot dogs"] = "Big No";

@NoobYT These solutions worked....they don't. Did you even test them all? Wimm's and u_mulder's suggestions are both wrong (demo 1: https://3v4l.org/E59pR, demo 2: https://3v4l.org/JhXEk). https://3v4l.org/LvWVo and https://3v4l.org/gcfnI show correct approaches (RiggsFolly's and mine). You can only select the best answer if someone actually writes a working answer. These are all comments, and Daniel Malmgren's answer below is also (at the time of writing) wrong.

Both RiggsFolly and I have now added formal answers below, if you want to select one of those.

@ADyson Pardon me for that. I have deleted the comment thanking him. I tried RiggsFolly's answer first and that's what worked. I have also accepted his answer. But, tell me what was missing from the original question. I have tried to be as detailed as possible. Is it just the print command? I am asking so that I could take care next time.

I told you already - you mentioned that you tried to use two different functions, array_push and array_merge, but then did not show your attempts to use them or explain what issue you had. You only showed your attempt using []

@ADyson Oh I get it now. Thank you for taking the time to clarify. Yes, it was my bad. Will include details of everything I tried as well next time.

You could use any of these methods below in the code, and maybe others also.
Uncomment one of the lines below and test them
$tblData[] = array(
    "Orange" => "Healthy",
    "Apple" => "Good",
    "Pizza" => "Bad",
);


#$tblData[0] += array("Hot dogs" => "Big No");
#$tblData = array_merge($tblData[0], array("Hot dogs" => "Big No"));

print_r($tblData);

They will all generate
Array
(
    [Orange] => Healthy
    [Apple] => Good
    [Pizza] => Bad
    [Hot dogs] => Big No
)


You're currently adding the new entry into the outer array. You need to add it to the inner one (situated at index 0 of the outer array). To do that, simply specify the index of the outer array you want to write to:
$tblData[0]["Hot dogs"] = "Big No";

Live demo: https://3v4l.org/gcfnI
N.B. This is just  one approach, there are several ways to solve it.
